# How to have a margin only when the preceding element is visible?

Tags: css

I have a series of  elements on my page followed by a breadcrumb .  Generally, the message elements are empty and don't display, but in the rare case where one of them has content and is visible, I'd like a margin on the breadcrumb element them so it is not flush up against the message. However, I don't want to add a margin otherwise.  Is there a way to do this purely with CSS?  The + operator will add the margin, but it doesn't go away if the div is not displayed.

```
<div class="message success"></div>
<div class="message error"></div>
<div class="breadcrumb>some content</div>

.message + .breadcrumb {
  margin-top: 10px; /*always there */
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't simply put the margin merely on the message class and then either only printing it when there's something to print, or just setting `display:none` when it's empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly-speaking, no: CSS has no means to select an element according to its visibility. You state that the preceding element is usually empty, though, and you want to add a margin only if it has content. That being the case, then:

```
/* styles the .breadcrumb with a margin-top */
.message + .breadcrumb {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
/* this rule is more specific, and so removes the margin-top if the .message
   element is truly empty (of everything, including text-nodes and white-space) */
.message:empty + .breadcrumb {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/v4sgh/).

The above will only work for the adjacent-siblings, if you're hoping to style the `margin-top` of `.breadcrumb` based on the existence of content in either, or both, of the `.message` elements, then that's a little trickier.

References:

- [`:empty` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#empty-pseudo).

Answer (score 0):

The rule have to be connected to "message error" element:

```
.error {
    ...
    border-bottom: solid 1pt black;/*whatever you want*/ 
    ...
}

.error:empty {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```